# Rails Ajax Call : Pass JSON to separate controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, shopify

Hey everyone I am having an issue setting up my app. It uses the shopify API and essentially what it does is grab some data via a view and sends it to the controller but I am having issues passing it to another method in the controller to use the API to save the data.

Here is my code :

**Controller**

```
class BuilderController < ShopifyApp::AuthenticatedController
  def index
    urlval = request.fullpath
    @urlCheck = urlval.split('/').last
  end
  def show
    url = request.fullpath
    @urlID = url.split('/').last
    @customers = ShopifyAPI::Customer.search(query: "id:"+ @urlID)
    #need to get a way to retrieve the ajax call info here to pass into    the update
  end
  def updateCustomer(notes)
      @customers.each do |cus|
      cus.note = notes
      cus.save()
      end
  end   
  def new
    notes = params[:notes]
    updateCustomer(notes)
    render json: notes
  end
end
```

**View**

```
    <button id="test">TEST</button>

<script>
var butt = document.getElementById('test');
butt.addEventListener("click",function(){
   $.ajax({
   url: "/builder/new",
   type: "GET", 
   data: {
            "notes": [
                "test",
                "test2"
            ]
        },
   success: function(data,text,xhr) {
       console.log(text);
       console.log(xhr);
       console.log(data);
       alert('successfully');
     },
   error: function(data,error){
        console.log(data);
        console.log(error);
        alert("help");
     }
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a fully separate method, have you looked into the 
respond_to method? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_to

You could do (assuming html is the primary request type, change if it isn't):

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { actions }
    format.json { actions }
  end
end
```

This the method we use to accommodate different request types within the same action.  Please let me know if I've misinterpreted your question.

Comment: the actions being my updatecustomer method implementation?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

> update_all(updates) public 
>   Updates all records with details given if
>   they match a set of conditions supplied, limits and order can also be
>   supplied. This method constructs a single SQL UPDATE statement and
>   sends it straight to the database. It does not instantiate the
>   involved models and it does not trigger Active Record callbacks or
>   validations.
>   http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all

```
def new
 notes = params[:notes]
 @customer.update_all({note: notes})

 respond_to do |format|
   format.html {}
   format.json { json: @customer.json }
 end
end
```

Comment: I am a bit confused as to why I would need a SQL type statement when I am not using a database for this at all? Maybe Im just misunderstanding